# What is the music played in this room in Postal 2?

Tags: game-music-identification, postal-2

Here you can see where it is on the map:

[image]

The room:

[image]

It is clearly a metal song, but I do not recognize who it played.

Does anyone who owns the game know which song it is?

*Given the recent incidents I won't upload a video of it to Youtube.*

Comment: Could it be in the [Soundtrack](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBF9C53FEA544DB9B) or maybe [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umwOQA_flLA)?

Comment: Do you have access to a phone with Shazam or something similar that can identify the music?

Comment: The actual audio would be quite useful in this instance...

Comment: @Kalina I agree but I am a Youtube Partner and I won't risk it.

Comment: There's a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSXT6f0D5zc) if anyone wants to listen to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Wrythe - On Silent Wings)
I was looking for it as well. Just typed in a few of the lyrics, and found it. Cheers, mate!

I just realised I was not in the exact place you were on the map, but rather close. I went to where you were, and didn't hear any music. I apologise if I was mistaken.

Though, the interior looks just like the one you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Not the only song that plays there, Vitharr, but this was one of them I couldn't find. I finally got smart enough to think to file dive into the installed files, the other song I have heard there is A Fall to Break - Stole My Faith.